# how to set a time bound for Regular expression match

Tags: python, regex

I am using regular expressions for text processing. For few sample texts, the Regex takes long time to process, because of which whole procedure is getting delayed.

I want to set a timer for the regex, so that if the regex exceeds the timer, skip the text and proceed further.

Is it possible to set in python ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to try and address why the regex takes a long time?... What have you tried so far?

Comment: Normally it is taking time whenever i have included .* type of expression. I have fixed as much possible. but  in a large amount of text it is difficult to track every exception. so i want to give a time bound.

Comment: It is not at all surprising that adding `.*` makes regex matching slower - the `.*` grabs the whole line/string and backtracks trying to accommodate text portions for the subpatterns after `.*`. The more there are subpatterns after `.*` the slower is the performance. Fix your regexps rather than setting any timeouts.

Comment: Is there a well-known non-backtracking regex library in Python?